# How to determine if Java process is running in Perl

Tags: perl, process, grep, ps

I have a suite of small Java app that all compiles/packages to `<name-of-the-app>.jar` and run  on  my server. Occasionally one of them will throw an exception, choke and die. I am trying to write a quick-n-dirty Perl script that will periodically poll to see if all of these executable JARs are still running, and if any of them are not, send me an email and notify me which one is dead.

To determine this manually, I have to run a `ps -aef | grep <name-of-app>` for each app I want to check. For example, to see if `myapp.jar` is running as a process, I run `ps -aef | grep myapp`, and look for a grep result that describes the JVM process representing `myapp.jar`. This manual checking is now getting tedious and is a prime candidate for automation!

I am trying to implement the code that checks to see whether a process is running or not. I'd like to make this a `sub` that accepts the name of the executable JAR and returns `true` or `false`:

```
sub isAppStillRunning($appName) {
    # Somehow run "ps -aef | grep $appName"

    # Somehow count the number of processes returned by the grep

    # Since grep always returns itself, determine if (count - 1) == 1.
    # If so, return true, otherwise, false.
}
```

I need to be able to pass the `sub` the name of an app, run my normal command, and count the number of results returned by `grep`. Since running a `grep` always results in at least one result (the `grep` command itself), I need logic that says if the (# of results - 1) is equal to 1, then we know the app is running.

I'm brand new to Perl and am having a tough time figuring out how to implement this logic. Here's my best attempt so far:

```
sub isAppStillRunning($appName) {
    # Somehow run "ps -aef | grep $appName"
    @grepResults = `ps -aef | grep $appName`;

    # Somehow count the number of processes returned by the grep
    $grepResultCount = length(@grepResults);

    # Since grep always returns itself, determine if (count - 1) == 1.
    # If so, return true, otherwise, false.
    if(($grepResultCount - 1) == 1)
        true
    else
        false
}
```

Then to call the method, from inside the same Perl script, I *think* I would just run:

```
&isAppStillRunning("myapp");
```

Any help with defining the sub and then calling it with the right app name is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perl can do this, but this is reinventing the wheel.  There are [many sysadmin solutions](http://serverfault.com/q/192302/17985) for restarting processes.

Comment: Re: grep matching its argument in the process table, the usual way to sidestep this is to `grep some[a]pp` rather than `grep someapp`.  Also, `grep -c some[a]pp` will portably give you the count of matches.

Comment: To add to what @pilcrow says, another thing I've done in the past is `grep process_name | grep -v grep` to avoid getting the grep process in its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sub is almost there, but the final if-else construct has to be corrected, and in some cases Perl idiom can make your life easier.

#### Perl Has Prototypes, But They Suck

```
sub isAppStillRunning($appName) {
```

will not work. Instead use

```
sub isAppStillRunning {
  my ($appName) = @_;
```

The `@_` array holds the arguments to the function.
Perl has some simple prototypes (the `sub name(&$@) {...}` syntax), but they are broken, and an advanced topic, so don't use them.

#### Perl Has Built-In Grep

```
`ps -aef | grep $appName`;
```

This returns one (1) string, possibly containing multiple lines. You could split the output at newlines, and grep manually, which is safer than interpolating variables:

```
my @lines   = split /\n/ `ps -aef`;
my @grepped = grep /$appName/, @lines;
```

You could also use the `open` function to explicitly open a pipe to `ps`:

```
my @grepped = ();
open my $ps, '-|', 'ps -aef' or die "can't invocate ps";
while (<$ps>) {
  push @grepped if /$appName/;
}
```

This is exactly equal, but better style. It reads all lines from the `ps` output and then pushes all lines with your `$appName` into the `@grepped` array.

#### Scalar vs. List Context

Perl has this unusual thing called "context". There is *list context* and *scalar context*. For example, subroutine calls take argument lists - so these lists (usually) have list context. Concatenating two strings is a scalar context, in contrast.

Arrays behave differently depending on their context. In *list context*, they evaluate to their elements, but in *scalar context*, they evaluate to the number of their elements. So there is no need to manually count elements (or use the `length` function that works on strings).

So we have:

```
 my @array = (1, 2, 3);
 print "Length: ", scalar(@array), "\n"; # prints "Length: 3\n"
 print "Elems: ", @array, "\n";          # prints "Elems: 123\n";
 print "LastIdx: ", $#array, "\n";       # prints "LastIdx: 2\n";
```

The last form, `$#array`, is the last index in the array. Unless you meddle with special variables, this is the same as `@array - 1`.

The `scalar` function forces scalar context.

#### Perl Has No Booleans

Perl has no boolean data type, and therefore no `true` or `false` keywords. Instead, all values are true, unless stated otherwise. False values are:

The empty string `""`, the number zero `0`, the string zero `"0"`, the special value `undef`, and some other oddities you won't run into.

So generally use `1` as true and `0` as false.

#### The if/else constructs require curly braces

So you probably meant:

```
if (TEST) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

which is the same as `return TEST`, where TEST is a condition.

#### The Ultimate reduction

Using these tricks, your sub could be written as short as

```
sub isAppStillRunning {
   return scalar grep /$_[0]/, (split /\n/, `ps -aef`);
}
```

This returns the number of lines that contain your app name.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @amon (+1) - great pointers! So, I assume I would then call the sub and check if the app is running or not by calling `if(isAppStillRunning('myapp') == 1)`? If the return value is 1 we know we have a match, right? Thanks again!

Comment: @4herpsand7derpsago No, the return value will not always be `1`. Treat the return value as a true or false value, i.e. `if (isAppStillRunning("yourapp"))` without further conditions.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But if "myapp" isn't running, I can always count on it being 0, right?

Comment: Sorry @amon, last question! If I wanted to check if "myapp" *isn't* running, how would I call `isAppStillRunning` if Perl doesn't support boolean? Could I use `if(!isAppStillRunning("myapp"))`, or would I have to change the logic inside the sub?

Comment: Just negate the return value (as you did). The `!` operator is possible; if you like it verbose, you can also use the `not` function that has the same effect.

Comment: Regarding checking for a negative condition, an elegant option in Perl is `unless (isAppStillRunning("myapp")) { ... }`.  This is exactly the same as `if (!...)`.

Answer (score 4):

It would be about a billion times easier to use the [Proc::ProcessTable](https://metacpan.org/module/Proc%3a%3aProcessTable) module from CPAN. Here's an example of what it might look like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::ProcessTable;

...
sub isAppStillRunning { 
    my $appname = shift;
    my $pt = Proc::ProcessTable->new;
    my @procs = grep { $_->fname =~ /$appname/ } @{ $pt->table };

    if ( @procs ) { 
        # we've got at least one proc matching $appname. Hooray!
    } else { 
        # everybody panic!
    }
}

isAppStillRUnning( "myapp" );
```

Some notes to keep in mind:

- Turn on [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html). They are your friends.
- You don't specify subroutine arguments with [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). (Prototypes in Perl do something completely different, which you don't want.) Use `shift` to get arguments off the `@_` array.
- Don't use `&` to call subroutines; just use its name.
- An array evaluated in scalar context (including if its inside an `if`) gives you its size. [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) doesn't work on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your routine like this:

```
sub isAppRunning {
    my $appName = shift;
    @grepResults = `ps -aef | grep $appName`;
    my $items = 0;
    for $item(@grepResults){
        $items++;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

This will iterate over the @grepResults and allow you to inspect the $item if necessary.

Calling it like this should return the number of processes:

```
print(isAppRunning('myapp') . "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks @jcern (+1) - 3 quick followups: (1) can you please explain the first line `my @appName = shift`? The `shift` is throwing me off!! (2) Are the curly braces around the body of the for-loop mandatory, or just good practice? Not sure if Perl enforces the braces even if there's only 1 statement. And (3) Does Perl not support boolean true/false values? I am wondering why you have the sub returning the item count and not true/false is all. Thanks again!

Comment: Running `grep $appName` as a subprocess will include the grep process in the count. It would be more accurate to capture `ps -aef` and grep the results in perl.

Comment: @4herpsand7derpsago (2) braces are almost always mandatory, as Perl is defined in terms of blocks, not statements, and blocks are delimited by braces. (3) see my answer to your question

Comment: For point 1, you can think of it this way, the arguments to the function are in the form of an array. You can pop the items from that array (or shift them) and assign them to a variable.  For (2) the braces are usually necessary. And (3) seems like it was answered pretty well in amon's answer.